# How to install SDK for Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I can download the iso with the SDK but which of the many *.msi do I need for C++ projects with MFC? There seemingly is no general installer included which installs the SDK on the fly.

Comment: Which SDK? I am not able to understand this question.

Comment: How are you installing Visual Studio? Nowadays you don't deal with all that stuff anymore. You just download the Visual Studio Installer, let it load/install everything and choose the appropriate workloads/components. In your case that would be the the "Desktop development with C++" workload, which it describes as "Build Windows desktop applications using the Microsoft C++ toolset, ATL, or MFC.".

Comment: This may help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: in VS2017 installer under individual components you can select MFC components

Answer (score 0):

When I installed Visual Studio 2019 I opted for C++ and MFC development and I thought that the installation of the SDK is then automatic - but somehow it was not. I de-installed and re-installed Visual Studio and then made sure that the SDK-box was checked.

Problem solved. Thanks.